# Android vmware port forwarding

Tags: android, vmware

I am running Windows os, on which I run ubuntu in vmware. I am facing some problem with launching avd in ubuntu, so I am running it on windows.
Now I need to access the avd on Windows inside Ubuntu(Vmware), how to do this. As far as i know, ports 5554 and 5555 need to be forwarded. 
So I selected custom NAT, and forwarded both tcp ports, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to select a "bridge" network type so that the GOS (guest operating system, in this case Ubuntu) receives an IP on your network, instead of an IP in a private range shared by your Windows host and the Ubuntu guest (I believe it's usually a 172.xx.xx.xx IP). In that scenario all is pretty straight forward within your network.

The next solution, which is slightly more complicated if you're trying to access the GOS from any other device on the network,  would be to use a host only NAT network between the Host (Windows) and the GOS(Ubuntu). In that case, you'd access the Ubuntu VM via it's nat IP from the Windows host. The downside is that these networks often have no outside connectivity (so you couldn't access the larger network or internet from the GOS (Ubuntu).